# Block in column has a too big margin from top

Tags: beamer, spacing

I want to use a two-column layout in my slides and place a block in each of these columns. Whenever I do this, the two boxes have a bigger distance from the top than when using a single box without columns.

See these two slides:

[image: Bug]

When not looking closely, one might not recognize the difference but when switching slides it is clearly visible that the distance between the frame-title and the start of the boxes is bigger on the two-column version.

Why is this the case? I checked multiple themes, it occured with each of them.

I want the two-column version to have the same distance from the top as the one column version. I think the spacing above the two column version is to big. By inserting `\hspace{-0.5cm}` in each of the columns (before the `\begin{block}`) I can achieve what I want but this is very hacky in my opinion.

Minimal working example (generating the two slides):

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame with Columns}
 \begin{columns}[t]
   \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Block 1}
        Text here
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Block 2}
        More text here
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame without Columns}
  \begin{block}{Block}
    Even more text here
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say this can be considered as a bug.

Answer (score 11):

It's a *feature*: a switch between vertical and horizontal mode.

Here is your MWE with a call to `\leavevmode`:

[image: example with a call to <code>\leavevmode</code>]

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame with Columns}
 \begin{columns}[t]
   \column{0.4\textwidth}
   \begin{block}{Block 1}
     Text here
   \end{block}
   \column{0.4\textwidth}
   \begin{block}{Block 2}
     More text here
   \end{block}
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame without Columns}
  \leavevmode\begin{block}{Block}
    Even more text here
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As suggested by percusse, to keep a minimal top margin you can use `\vspace` with a negative distance (here, I choose `-\baselineskip`):

[image: second version]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame with Columns}

  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Block 1}
      Text here
    \end{block}
    \column{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Block 2}
      More text here
    \end{block}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame without Columns}
  \begin{block}{Block}
    Even more text here
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but now I have the big margins on both frames. Can I somehow get the narrow margins? I think the wide spacing is to big.

Comment: @theomega Then you can introduce a `\vspace{-2.75ex}` just before the `columns` environment to level.

Comment: @percusse how did you calculate the value -2.75ex? Is it theme dependent, because for my situation it is too large. (Also -\baselineskip is too much).

Comment: Ok, in [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119725/inconsistent-margins-using-columns-in-beamer] I found a hint to `[onlytextwidth,t]` which apparently made `-2.75ex` to be the right value. I do not know whats going on behind the scenes, but It works now :-)

Comment: Any explanation as to why this extra space can be considered a *feature* and not a bug?

Comment: @Lorents The difference between a feature and a bug is sometimes minimal, if any. ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Of course, many things can be both useful and annoying! But when is this different top margin useful?

Comment: @Lorents This feature will become a bug if someone [signals it as such](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/new)...