# Inconsistent margins using columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, margins, two-column

Compare the two slides generated by the following code.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \lipsum
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \lipsum
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice how, in two-column mode, the side-margins are smaller, and the top margin is larger. This makes the layout on my slides inconsistent when I mix a two-column and one-column layout, particularly if I do so on the same slide.

How do I get LaTeX to stop messing with margins in two-column mode?

Thanks,
-Willard.

P.S.: In case someone else has the same issue: In two-column mode, if I had an image in one column, then placing a theorem in the other column would move the image. I traced this issue to

```
\setbeamercolor{structure}{...}
```

which apparently does more than just colour things. To change colors, use

```
\usecolortheme[...]{structure}
```

instead.

Answer (score 12):

Try `[onlytextwidth,t]` instead of `[T]` (p. 125, [beamer manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#125)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,t]
    \begin{column}{0.49\linewidth}
      \lipsum[6]
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.49\linewidth}
      \lipsum[6]
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about that one!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is 'status bydesign': looking over the code, the decision to have different margins is one that was made deliberately and not an accident/bug. As such, and because a change would affect many documents, it has to be viewed as a 'feature' of `beamer`. (There is no clue in the code as to *why* this decision was made!)

Answer (score 1):

For a document-wide solution, you can use the `onlytextwidth` class option (requires beamer v3.65 or newer)

```
\documentclass[t,onlytextwidth]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \lipsum
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \lipsum
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```